# Need to Copy a Method To File.txt

Tags: c#, .net

```
public int UpdateTable()
{

string SpName="UPDATE_TABLE_S1";
.
.
.//statement 30

return recordsaffected = 1;
}

public int InsertTable()
{

string SpName="Insert_TABLE_S1";
.
.
.
return recordsaffected = 1;
}

public int DeleteTable()
{

string SpName="DELETE_TABLE_S1";
.
.
return recordsaffected = 1;
}
```

There is class which has around 20 methods and i need to copy a method by Searching a SpName = 'INSERT_TABLE_S1' To Text File.

i used stream reader to search the sp name. but copying the whole method is where i am struck. Is there any in built method to copy the whole method.

i tried by writing to file when public keyword starts and till the return comes.. but this doesn't seem correct...

Comment: no - there is no such method in the framework... instead of copying until the `return` comes use the opening `{` and closing `}` as your guides esp. since a method might have several `return` statements

Comment: thanks let me check with { n see

Comment: beware that `{}` can be nested (though always in pairs) so you need to keep track of the nesting level to make it work properly

Comment: What do you mean, "copy the method"? Do you mean copy a piece of your source code?

Answer (score 0):

I'd be inclined to start storing methods in a string builder one line at a time until either the method ends or the string you are looking for is found.  If it is found finish reading the method and write to your external file.  Maybe even store all the methods in a list of string builders so I could search through them all at the end.

I'd probably extract an interface which I would use to give me a list of all the method signatures which I could use to start reading in each method.

Answer (score 0):

You can split based on public keyword and then search for the method name:

```
        string spName = "DELETE_TABLE_S1";
        string methodText = "";
        string[] methods = theCompleteStringWithAllMethods.Split(new string[] { "public"     }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        for (int ii = 0; ii < methods.Length; ii++)
        {
            if (methods[ii].Contains("SpName=" + spName))
            {
                methodText = "public " + methods[ii];
                break;
            }
        }
```